# Invoking a method defined into a running Figure

Tags: matlab, class, properties, function-handle, matlab-app-designer

I have the following `UIFigure`:

```
classdef gui < matlab.apps.AppBase
   ...
   function app = gui
      % Construct app
   end
   ...
   properties (Access = public)
      myFuncRef = @myFun
   end
   ...
   function myFun(app)
      % do something
   end
   ...
end
```

in which I have defined the method `myFun`.

If the figure is running (that is, it's showing a window), how can I invoke the method `myFun` from the Command Window of MATLAB ? I tried with

```
h = findobj(0, 'type', 'figure');
funcRef = get(h, 'myFuncRef');
funcRef(h);
```

but I get the error

> An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was
>   terminated Caused by: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values
>   of class 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
h = findobj(gcf,'-method','myFuncRef')
```

or

```
h = findobj(0,'class','gui')
```

let me know if it works

The probelm is probably that you get just your figure with `findobj(0, 'type', 'figure')`, this is just a Grahics Obejct which is manimulated by the App-Class.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried the sequence h = findobj(0, 'class', 'gui'); funcRef = get(h, 'myFuncRef'); funcRef(h); and it gave me the same error. When I try h = findobj(gcf,'-method','myFuncRef') it doesn't give me an error but it opens a window and it doesn't work however.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to address the error you're getting. The reason for it is that the `h` returned by your call to `findobj()` is empty. Instead you should use `findall(0,'Type','Figure',...)` [[src]](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/284811-how-to-get-uifigure-handle).

I know this is possible when the method you're referencing is `static`. Considering the following class:

```
classdef q45062561 < matlab.apps.AppBase

   properties (Access = public)
      myFuncRef = @q45062561.myFun
   end

   methods (Access = private, Static = true)
     function myFun()
        disp('This works!')
     end
   end

end
```

Then, running the following would yield the desired result:

```
>> F = q45062561;
>> F.myFuncRef()
This works!
```

**Notes:**

1. Rather than finding the handle of the figure via `findobj`, I'm just storing it during creation.
2. The modifiers of `myFun` are unclear from the question so I can't know if this solution is suitable in your case.
3. Personally, I think it's a better idea to just define the method `public` and/or `static`, instead of using a function reference stored in a property.